# Managing many classes through single object

Tags: design-patterns

I don't know if this is the correct way to go about this or if I'm making this overly complex but I have an interface that's implemented by many other classes and a single class creates these the objects that have this interface and passes that. The idea is to allow for adding new features to be easy just by creating a class that implements that interface without needing to change other code. Thoughts?

An example could be with JTabbedPane and Panes (Tabs). In a package, you could have all these Classes that implement an interface called Tab. During runtime the Class with JTabbedPane makes a call to another Class object (or util) called Tabs and Tabs reads all Classes in a package which hold Tab type Classes. Tabs creates the object and then passes on. This way the code never needs to be edited when you add a new feature such as a new tab.

Comment: This sounds like standard inheritance, but i am not sure i understand your question. What do you mean by adding new feature? Can you give an sample use case?

Comment: Features being just adding new parts to your program.